# Someone broke my picture

Tags: bug, gravatar

My picture appears somehow broken on my profile.

> [image]

But it comes out perfectly in smaller formats (questions and answers gravatar).

> [image]

I'm sure I'm not the first one to point out this issue but I can't find my answer on the site. 
Also, I want to find a fix...

Comment: Looks like a imgur problem; try re-uploading. http://i.stack.imgur.com/V6QVt.jpg?s=128&g=1 is indeed borken for me.

Comment: Original size http://i.stack.imgur.com/V6QVt.jpg works just fine.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Looking at the title I get why I didn't find it -_- thanks.

Comment: Martijn's dedication to truth would indicate that it is a dupe; makes me look too lazy :-).

Comment: I had this problem a few times on normal imgur when uploading photos. Deleting it and re-uploading is usually the only solution.