# Let's play Space Invaders!

Tags: bug, status-declined, user-interface

[image]

Not exactly a huge bug, but I think one loader would suffice.
For the record, my connection dropped in the exact moment I clicked the *flag* link and every further click spawned a new loader (kind of entertaining, though. I might open a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)).

Comment: By the way, I just cast a close vote on my own question. [Where's my badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203988/badge-for-close-voting-own-question-after-someone-close-voted-it)

Comment: Not fair, you posted the same bug in such a better way! ;)

Comment: What is this? I don't even.

Comment: and meta has a long an illustrious history of [marvelously reported bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166575/179419) that [no one is able to find](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197775/someone-broke-my-picture?lq=1#comment626209_197775)

Comment: I think a feature request would be appropriate. I usually like to see how many of the ellipses I can get on screen before the thing actually loads when this happens to me. It's a fun game.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Well, it has been [meta-tag:status-declined] (not [meta-tag:status-bydesign]), which is usually reserved for [meta-tag:feature-request]s, so creating a feature request is unlikely to make a difference (at least in theory anyway).